# jQuery reload page not refreshing content

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, reload

I'm using jQuery to post a form to a handler script using AJAX.  Upon completion, I'm refreshing the page - however, the content doesn't actually refresh unless I do a Shift-F5 refresh on the page.  This is obviously bad, as the user thinks that their submission didn't take.

I've tried doing location.href = location.href.
I've tried doing location.reload(true);
I've tried appending random variables to the end of the page to force it to load a new one.
I've tried putting in my Page_Load of my usercontrol to look for these variables, and if they exist, rebind the data
I've tried doing the same as above, except in the parent page for this usercontrol.
I've tried disabling page chaching for this page.
I've tried disabling viewstate for the control (A Literal control, which is displaying an assembled HTML table and form on the backend)

```
$(".saveButton").click(function () {
            $(".timeEntry").each(function () {
                var dayCount = $(this).attr('data-day');
                var chargecode = $(this).attr('data-chargecodeid');
                var chargetype = $(this).attr('data-chargetypeid');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "_PostTime.aspx",
                    data: {
                        "UserID": "<%: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() %>",
                        "Hours": $(this).val(),
                        "DayCount": dayCount.replace("Day", ""),
                        "ChargeCodeID": chargecode,
                        "ChargeTypeID": chargetype
                    },
                    datatype: "text",
                    success: function () {
                        //Do nothing
                    }                        
                });                                                                                          
            });

            location.reload();
        });
```

Executing the above code correctly submits the form and reloads the page upon completion - however, regardless of what I try, the page remains in the original state until the user *manually* refreshes the browser.

At this point I'm at a loss for what's going on.  I've confirmed there are no errors in my ASP.NET code, and no jQuery errors in the browser console.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is async. it means that if you place a code after `$.ajax()`, it wont run after ajax.

so you should wait for all of your ajax calls to complete, then refresh the page.
you can use `.ajaxStop` for such thing.

```
//after loop
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the reload into the success function. It will reload upon success:

```
$(".saveButton").click(function () {
            $(".timeEntry").each(function () {
                var dayCount = $(this).attr('data-day');
                var chargecode = $(this).attr('data-chargecodeid');
                var chargetype = $(this).attr('data-chargetypeid');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "_PostTime.aspx",
                    data: {
                        "UserID": "<%: HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId() %>",
                        "Hours": $(this).val(),
                        "DayCount": dayCount.replace("Day", ""),
                        "ChargeCodeID": chargecode,
                        "ChargeTypeID": chargetype
                    },
                    datatype: "text",
                    success: function () {
                      window.location.reload(); // like this
                    }                        
                });                                                                                          
            });
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as it's a foreach loop, meaning the refresh would begin to take place after the first successful call.  Also, this doesn't address the underlying problem - the page reloads, it just doesn't refresh the content.  Lastly, I had tried this before posting for help, but thank you anyway.